# prepared statement executes, but i can't fetch the results

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm was doing this tutorial[How to create a login system in PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8TP2FERKls)

I'm trying to use an IF statement to check if to set the session id.  The current allows a user to log in and echos the current session id. When I purposely enter a wrong password, the code should echo a message, but it doesn't do anything.  In addition, I am unable to use the logout button to kill the session.

Here is my login page

```
<?php
session_start();
//include 'dbh.php';
    //probably do not need this can write connection in this file too
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testtable', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if(!$conn){
            die("Connection is fubar yo!!! ");
        }

    $uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_REQUEST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";

    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    if(!$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo("Your username or Password is wrong");
    } else {
        echo("hey man..it works");
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    }

    header("Location: fakelogin.php");

?>
```

Here is my logout page.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();


header("Location: fakelogin.php");

?>
```

here is the main page that contains login, signup and logout buttons.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Look ma, no hands!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Enter  username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
        <button type="submit" id="login">LOGIN</button>
    </form>

    <?php
        echo("testing");
        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            echo($_SESSION['id']);
        } else {
            echo("You are not logged in");
        }
    ?>
    <br><br><br>
    <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Enter first name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Enter last name"><br>
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Enter  username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
        <button type="submit" id="sbt">SIGN UP HERE YO!</button>
    </form>

    <br><br><br>

    <form>
        <button action="logout.php">LOG OUT</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should probably comment out the header redirect when testing.

Comment: I took it out of both.  I didn't see a change.  Just for the record, why is it a good idea to remove it when testing?

Comment: You won't be able to see the result because you will just be seeing `fakelogin.php` or whatever page you redirected to after the process is done if you leave the redirect in. After loading your login page, do you get redirected to fakelogin.php? Or do you stay at the login page?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the fakelogin.php page which contains login/signup/logout

Comment: Do you destroy the session when you logout of a previous user? If not, `if(isset($_SESSION['id']))` will say that the variable is set because of the previous setting.

Comment: How would I destroy a session after a logout of a previous user?  I thought that once I hit the logout button..it would destroy the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have provided, you will always return to the login page.

When logged in, the string below login button will say **testing** followed by your user account id.

Otherwise, it will show **testingYou are not logged in**.

You cannot add a message on `login.php` and expect it to appear on `fakelogin.php` auto-magically.

There are a lot of ways to share information between pages and the session variable is one of it.

By using the method below, you can set the session variable `id` as "Your username or Password is wrong" and since `fakelogin.php` will print it out if there's a value, this should show the error message.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//include 'dbh.php';
    //probably do not need this can write connection in this file too
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testtable', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if(!$conn){
            die("Connection is fubar yo!!! ");
        }

    $uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_REQUEST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";

    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    if(!$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo("Your username or Password is wrong");
        $_SESSION['id'] = "Your username or Password is wrong";
    } else {
        echo("hey man..it works");
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    }

    header("Location: fakelogin.php");

?>
```

So when you attempt to login with wrong details, you will see **testingYour username or Password is wrong**.

For problem with your logout button, there's a problem with your HTML. `action` attribute should be in the `form` tag and not the `button` tag like so.

```
<form action="logout.php">
    <button>LOG OUT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome response!  Thank you!